# Conditions and method-calling efficiency

Tags: function, methods, if-statement

Is it faster, slower, or the same to have a condition to check whether a method should be called, vs calling a method and having a condition in there to check whether it should run its contents?

```
if (cond) {
  doThis();
}
method doThis() {
  // do things
}
```

vs

```
doThis();
method doThis() {
  if (cond) {
    // do things
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be noticeably different either way. This should really be based on convention. Can the method still do its job if the condition is not met? Then you should check the condition in the method:

```
doThis();
method doThis() {
    if(!cond) throw new InvalidOperationException();
    // do things
}
```

If the method can still operate if the condition is not met, but you only want to call the method when the condition is met, then do the check outside of the method:

```
if(cond) doThis();
method doThis() {
    // do things
}
```